# Rails ERD Customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erd

Can you help me use the ***Customization Options*** of Rails ERD to generate a diagram that displays the **primary keys** and **timestamps** attributes.

How do I write this into irb terminal?  This is what I tried:

```
$ rake erd primary_keys, timestamps
```

GitHub lists the ***Customization Options***, but I'm not understanding how to write the **attributes**.

```
attributes             <type,...> | false

  Specifies which attributes to include in the diagram output. This can be any   
  combination of the following attribute types:

  foreign_keys  any foreign key column in use for associations
  primary_keys  the primary key column (typically id)
  timestamps    any of the 'magic' timestamp columns (created_at/on,updated_at/on)
  inheritance   the single table inheritance column (typically type)
  *content       all other columns
  *To hide attributes altogether, set this option to false. Default value: content
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant to tag this with `erd` not `erb`...

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be `rake erd attributes=primary_keys,timestamps`.

Comment: Tried this and got it returned back:

Comment: it's `rake erd attributes=primary_keys,timestamps` without the 2 dashes.